# WiX - Suppress / Ignore version

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I am developing an installer for our companies application using WiX.

One of the things I've noticed when testing is that running the same installer twice (after a successful install) causes the install to be aborted because the same version of the software already exists. I need behaviour that allows the same installer to run multiple times, and install the same application multiple times.

This is because when we deploy to our clients (which has been manual) we always deploy in both a Test Environment and a Production Environment. The code bases for the two environments are identical. Additionally some clients wish to have multiple production / test environments on the same machine.

Is there a way to suppress the version information for the installer, so that it will ignore any previous installations and install again? I've tried so far suppressing PublishProduct, but it does not give this behaviour. It appears that the version attribute is also required (I cannot remove it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run both installation on the same machine you will need to:

- Change the product code to "*".
- Remove upgrade code or change it for each installer.
- Change the path of the installation for each install.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to have a MajorUpgrade element in your install, sequence it afterInstallInitialize (so it uninstalls the older version then installs the new) and also set AllowSameVersionUpgrades to true.  You will need to have the ProductCode and PackageCode values to * so each build creates new guids. Basically it's the ProductCode that says a product is installed and you can't install the same product twice - it needs an upgrade.